Using PyExiftool library to get output equivalent to the command line "-s -f -listx > test.xml"
I'm trying to get an XML database listing from Exiftool using the PyExiftool library.
Right now, I have been unable to come up with an acceptable way to compose a command line for this library from within a Python (wxPython) project.
All I get are various error messages, depending on how I pass the command line arguments to
exiftool.execute.
For the command line version, I can execute
"exiftool -s -f -listx > d:\newXmlFile.xml"
and get a rather long & big XML file copied into d:\newXmlFile.xml
TIA for any pointers or advice if this is possible and how to go about it.

Do you have some example code and the errors it returns?  I don't know python, but looking over the docs, it looks like you just need to assign the execute to a variable to capture the exiftool output. Something along these lines maybe XML_Results=exiftool.ExifTool.execute("-s","-f","-listx") If you needed it in a file, you would then just save the variable to a file.  You can't redirect the exiftool output with > as that is a function of the command line only, not something that exiftool would even know about.

My current code is: 'code' string = et.execute( "-ver")
print( string )
string = et.execute( "-s -f -listx") 'code' The first line is accepted, the second call bombs with an error: "ExifToolEecuteError: execute returned a non-zero exit status". FWIW, the string to be reurned could run into several MBs

I think you are passing "-s -f -listx" as a single option, not as separate options. I don't see anything on the examples page that indicates you can do this. All the examples separate all the options.  Try formatting it as I did in my first comment.

@StarGeek: Thank you ever so much. That is exactly what I needed to get the string back. I had tried codestring = et.execute( common_args=['-s', '-f', '-listx'])code , but that failed as well. Now I just need to parse that string and build a db ;-)

I believe that common_args has to be used at startup only. I'm assuming it is using exiftool's -Common_Args option, which cannot be used once exiftool has started as a background process, only at the beginning.

Thank you for the additional information. At the time I tried that option, I was desperate for any solution. Meanwhile, with your help I have resolved  my issues in this respect :-)
